# error: G_SOURCE_FUNC while running chef.py

Tags: google-smart-home

```
When we run ./chef.py -zbr -d rootnode_dimmablelight_bCwGYSDpoe -t linux we get G_SOURCE_FUNC error , how can we solve this?


We installed Docker on Ubuntu 18.04
We downloaded Docker image
We run Docker
https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-device-virtual#1 we completed the steps here
We created a project in Google Home Developer Console
We upgraded python 3.8, we upgraded gcc and g++ 9
We tried Include <glib.h>, define the callback as a GSourceFunction variable and pass that callback to the function
```

(I'am using ubuntu 18.04. I did all the updates and followed the steps to install docker. Also glib version is GLIBC 2.27)

Comment: G_SOURCE_FUNC, seems to be related to the usage of a callback function in your code. Check callback function implementation..

Answer (score 0):

We ran the setup successfully with the latest long term support release  of Ubuntu (22.04) and did not encounter any issues.
Please give it a try with the latest version of Ubuntu. If the issue still persists I recommend opening up a ticket on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) in this regard.